# How to get all the cookies issued by facebook?

Tags: cookies, browser

I know that I can get cookies for a specific domain using

```
document.cookie
```

in web browser. 
When I use this function on facebook.com I get the following result

```
 act=xxxxxxx%2F3; 
 locale=en_GB; 
 c_user=xxxxxxxxx; 
 csm=2; 
 p=-2; 
 presence=xxxxxxxxxuserFA2xxxxxxxA2EstateFDutF1476186588283CEchFDp_5fxxxxxxxxxC"
```

but when I look at the request made from browser , there are more cookies in Request header.

```
    cookie:datr=xxxxxxx; 
           locale=en_GB; 
           sb=xxxxxxx; 
           c_user=xxxxxxx;
           xs=xxxxxxxxx; 
           csm=2; 
           s=xxxxxxx; 
           lu=xxxxx; 
           p=-2;  
           presence=xxxxxxxx; 
           wd=489x674;
```

So where are these other cookies stored in browser?

why can't I get those using document.cookie function?

Thanks

Comment: Not all cookies are accessible with javascript and so some cookies aren't reflected by document.cookies

Comment: @Axnyff is there specific reason for that ? security issue or something like that ?

Comment: I'm not an expert at all on this subject, it seems to be linked to XSS attacks: https://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/

Comment: what do you want to achieve? it is a lot easier to help with that information.

Comment: @luschn I want to get all the cookies issued by facebook

Comment: @Axnyff
this may be the reason


 
 "When you tag a cookie with the HttpOnly flag, it tells the browser that this particular cookie should only be accessed by the server. Any attempt to access the cookie from client script is strictly forbidden."





Thanks for your link. It was helpful

Comment: we know that, but WHY exactly? what do you want to do with the cookies?